# Find line with close curly bracket "}" but not with semicolon ";" or comma ","

Tags: regex, curly-braces

I am trying to find a regex to meet my requirement. I want to match lines with a close curly bracket but should not contain semicolon or comma. There may be a space or tab before the bracket. There may be a space or other characters between the bracket and semicolon/comma.

An example

```
Match: 

[sapce/tab] }  
} /\* abcde \*/
} else { // abcde
```

```
Ignore:

};  
} abc;
},
```

This is what I have managed so far:

```
^\s*(?=}).*(?!;)\s\*$
```

But it matches `};` and `} ,` among others which is not what I want. I have also tried this

```
^\s*}[^;,][0-9A-Za-z_/\*\\{]\s*$
```

but it ignores `} abc;` and `} else {`.

Comment: Consider using an online regex tester to help you with problems like these, such as http://regexplanet.com or http://debuggex.com

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
^[^,;]*\}[^,;]*$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. It also seems to work for me.